# diffrent serial no for each ID in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table  where I Have 2 ids
table is like

```
ID    Date                       Shift(hr)   serial no 
54     11/10/2020                 2           1
54     10/10/2020                 5           2 
53     11/10/2020                 4           3
53     10/10/2020                 5           4
```

I want Output as below
table is like

```
ID    Date                       Shift(hr)   serial no 
54     11/10/2020                 2           1
54     10/10/2020                 5           2 
54     09/10/2020                 6           3
53     11/10/2020                 4           1
53     10/10/2020                 5           2
```

Like based on date serial no should come for each ID  numbering should start from the latest date
Kindly Suggest something thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select id, date, Shift, 
       row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as serial_no
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer  really helpful

Comment: @AkashSingh, Please don't forget to mark it as accepted :)